# Почему "лабиовелярный" пишется слитно?

Tags: терминология, слитно-дефис

По определению *лабиовелярный* звук — тот, что образуется с помощью губ и нёба, а не "губного нёба".

Почему это слово пишется слитно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это слово не может писаться через дефис, хотя здесь **сочинительная** связь основ.

В русском языке есть слова ***лабиальный, лабиализованный***, поэтому в сложном слове  основа первого прилагательного **усеченная**.

Дефисное написание было бы возможно для сложного слова ***лабиально-велярный***.